# Spring JPA DDL file generation - how to delete or clean file before generating

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, ddl

I am using this setup to generate a ddl file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=./ddl/schema.sql
```

The generation is executed via a specific test in Maven validation phase:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/ddl.properties")
public class GenerateDDL {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void generateDDL() throws IOException {
        em.close();
        em.getEntityManagerFactory().close();
    }

}
```

This is working fine, with on problem: the generator does not create a new file but just appends always it's stuff.

Is there a way or setting to let generator always create a new file or clean up the old?

Deleting it within the test would delete it after generation. We also need the file to be published on git thus it is not generated within `target`.

**UPDATE**
There seems at least no solution within Hibernate (until Hibernate 6):
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11817

Is there a way to hook into Spring context creation - before persistence context is created? There i could delete the file.

Comment: Delete the file using maven on startup?

Comment: this would be a bad option - the test should have the same out if run from maven or IDE. But there seems no other option?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: Assuming your spring boot project includes a version of Hibernate **>= 5.5.3**, then to configure the schema file(s) to be **overwritten** (i.e. *disable* appending) you would add this entry in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema-generation.script.append=false
```

---

Since [Hibernate version 5.5.3](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11817?jql=project%20%3D%20%22HHH%22%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%225.5.3%22) there is a new property available that can be set to **disable** the appending behaviour.  From the Hibernate User Guide:

> ##### [**26.15. Automatic schema generation**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)
>
> `hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema-generation.script.append` (e.g. `true` (default value) or `false`)
>
> For cases where the `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action` value indicates that schema commands should be written to DDL script file, `hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema-generation.script.append` specifies if schema commands should be appended to the end of the file rather than written at the beginning of the file. Values are `true` for appending schema commands to the end of the file, `false` for writing achema commands at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I was faced with the same problem, and found the following way to clean up before schema generation: use BeanFactoryPostProcessor. BeanFactoryPostProcessor is called when all bean definitions are loaded, but no beans are instantiated yet.

```
 /**
 * Remove auto-generated schema files before JPA generates them.
 * Otherwise new content will be appended to the files.
 */
@Configuration
public class SchemaSupport {

    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor schemaFilesCleanupPostProcessor() {
        return bf -> {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(Path.of("schema-drop-auto.sql"));
                Files.deleteIfExists(Path.of("schema-create-auto.sql"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short example using Gradle and Springboot.
Assuming you have a project property defining your environment, and "dev" is the one creating DDL files for Postgres.

Excerpt from application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    database: POSTGRESQL
    properties:
      javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action: drop-and-create
      javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action: drop-and-create
      javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target: ./sql/create-postgres.sql
      javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-source: metadata
      javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target: ./sql/drop-postgres.sql
      javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-source: metadata
```

Add some code in bootRun task to delete the files:

```
bootRun {
def defaultProfile = 'devtest'
def profile = project.hasProperty("env") ? project.getProperty("env") : defaultProfile
if (profile == 'dev') {delete 'sql/create-postgres.sql'; delete 'sql/drop-postgres.sql';}
```

...}

Answer (score 0):

I only ever use the schema file for testing and solved the problem by specifying the location of the output file as follows:

`spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=target/test-classes/schema.sql`

This works well for Maven but the target directory could be modified for a Gradle build.