# spring data jpa append the create statements each time I run the project as spring app,

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a problem with the spring jpa schema generation. I set the following properties in the application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-source=metadata
```

Then each time I run the project or I build it as maven build it appends all the create statements to the create.sql file. I tried to put the create.sql in the target path then each time it removes it and then create a new one but I get an error that it can not read the create.sql. Any idea how to stop appending the create statements each time at the end of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JPA DDL file generation - how to delete or clean file before generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730890/spring-jpa-ddl-file-generation-how-to-delete-or-clean-file-before-generating)

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate of [Spring JPA DDL file generation - how to delete or clean file before generating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75087226/998793) - I have described a solution there that works for Hibernate versions **>= 5.5.3**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema-generation.script.append=false
```