# How to overwrite instead of append SQL-Schema definitions with auto schema-generation in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I configured my Spring Boot Project to create a SQL file from my Entities with Hibernate:

```
spring:
  profiles: devlocal
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: "create-drop"
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name: "UTF-8"
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            scripts:
              action:  "drop-and-create"
              create-target: "src/main/resources/data/definition/create.sql"
              drop-target: "src/main/resources/data/definition/drop.sql"
              create-source: "metadata"
              drop-source: "metadata"
    open-in-view: true
```

When executing, the sql statements are appended to the *create.sql* and *drop.sql* that they grow longer with every build. Is there a configurative possibility to overwrite/replace it instead?

Comment: Such a weird behaviour, have you found anything as of today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer, see [Spring JPA DDL file generation - how to delete or clean file before generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730890/spring-jpa-ddl-file-generation-how-to-delete-or-clean-file-before-generating)

you hast have to add `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema-generation.script.append` and set it to `false`

Works from Hibernate 5.6 onwards.

```
spring:
  profiles: devlocal
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: "create-drop"
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name: "UTF-8"
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema-generation.script.append: false
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            scripts:
              action:  "drop-and-create"
              create-target: "src/main/resources/data/definition/create.sql"
              drop-target: "src/main/resources/data/definition/drop.sql"
              create-source: "metadata"
              drop-source: "metadata"
```